# Добавление параметров в requests

Tags: python, curl, requests, ssl, сертификат

Хочу использовать python requests вместо использования cURL в коде.
Так выглядит api в документации:

```
$ curl -v  \
-H Referer:https://server.example.com/ \
-H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "Accept:text/plain" \
-c $COOKIEJAR -b $COOKIEJAR \
--cacert /etc/ipa/ca.crt  \
--data "user=$_USERNAME&password=$_PASSWORD" \
-X POST \
https://server.example.com/session/login_password
```

Так я пытаюсь его конвертировать в requests:

```
  cookies = {
  }

  headers = {
    'referer': 'https://servername/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'text/plain',
  }

  data = {
    'user': 'login',
    'password': 'pass'
     }
  cacert = {
    'cacert' : '/etc/ca.crt'
    }
  response = requests.post('https://servername/login_password', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data, cacert=cacert)
```

Часть с `cacert` не работает, т.к `response` не в курсе опции `cacert`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification):

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, 
                         data=data, verify='/path/to/certfile')
```